# EJB: Lock access to a method only instead of whole bean instance

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

In my application I am providing some application wide data in a `@Singleton` EJB. The preperation of the data is a long running task. However, the underlying source of this outcome is changing frequently, so I have to recalculated the data which is populated by the Singleton frequently as well.

The task now is to ensure a quick access to the data, even if it is currently recalculated. It does not matter if I am exposing the old status, while the preparation is ongoing.

My current approach looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class MySingleton {

    @Inject private SomeService service;       
    @Getter private SomeData currentVersion;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
        currentVersion = service.longRunningTask();
    }

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    @AccessTimeout(value = 1, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    @Asynchronous
    public void catchEvent(
                 @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) MyEvent event) {
        this.update();            
    }        
}
```

The idea behind this is to prepare the data once on startup. Afterwards the clients are able to access the current version of my data (consider this data as immutable) concurrently.

Now, if some action happens that may cause a recalculation of the data, I am fireing a CDI event and in the Singleton I am observing this event and triggering the recalculation again. Those actions may happen quite often in a short period of time (but also there might be none of those actions for a long time).

- I marked the method as @Asynchronous so it is executed, so other clients may still access the getter concurrently in different thread of execution.
- I marked it as LockType.Write and with the AccessTimeout, because I want to drop redundant events, when they are occuring in a short period of time.

The Problem is obvious:

- If I am using the `LockType.WRITE` then the access to the getter methods is locked as well, during the recalculation.
- If I am not using it I while end up in heavy ressource consumption when there are many CDI events observed

Is it possible to lock the access to this single method only instead of locking access to the whole instance of my singleton? Would this solve my problem? Any other approaches how I may handle my problem?

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A: Never have more than 1 thread waiting:**

- Try to get a WriteLock for this method only.  If it getting the lock succeeds, update and unlock.
- If tryLock does not succeed, check if there is already a thread waiting to get the WriteLock.

  - If there is a thread already waiting, abort the method since we don't want 2 threads waiting on the WriteLock at the same time.
  - If there are not other threads waiting to get a lock, wait on a WriteLock and then update.

.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class MySingleton {

    private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    // ...

    @Asynchronous
    public void catchEvent(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) MyEvent event) 
    {
        try{
            if(!lock.writeLock().tryLock()){
                // Unable to immediately obtain lock

                if(lock.hasQueuedThreads()){
                    // there is *probably* at least 1 thread waiting on
                    // the lock already, don't have more than 1 thread waiting
                    return;
                } else {
                    // There are no other threads waiting.  Wait to acquire lock
                    lock.writeLock().lock();
                    this.update();
                }
            } else {
                // obtained the lock on first try
                this.update();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                lock.writeLock().unlock();
            } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException ignore){}
        }
    }        
}
```

**Note:** Brett Kail pointed out that there could be a race condition here where two threads go through the `tryLock()` and `lock.hasQueuedThreads()` at the same time and one of them gets the write lock while the other blocks for the full duration of `this.update()`.  This could potentially happen, but I think this is rare enough that the advantage of not waiting at all *most* of the time outweighs waiting 1 minute *most* of the time.

---

**Option B: Never have any threads waiting:**
I'm not sure how steadily your events come in, but it would simplify the logic much more if you just aborted if `tryLock()` returned false, however you wouldn't get as many updates.

```
@Asynchronous
public void catchEvent(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) MyEvent event) 
{
    if(!lock.writeLock().tryLock())
        return; // there is already an update processing

    try{
        this.update();
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

---

**Option C: Wait for up to X amount of time for a lock (mimmic @AccessTimeout)** 
Brett pointed out in the comments that option A has a race condition and could potentially have a thread block for the full duration of `this.update()`, and suggested this approach as a safer alternative.  The only drawback is that `tryLock()` will end up timing out most of the time, so setting the timeout as small as possible is advantageous.

```
@Asynchronous
public void catchEvent(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) MyEvent event) 
{

    if(lock.writeLock().tryLock(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
        try{
            this.update();
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case I would end up with a bunch of threads of execution pending, and all of them would be executed one by one, won't I? So in fact the EJB TimeOut would be meaningless, am I correct? I want to avoid that because there might be dozends or even hundreds of such events in a very short period of time. Ideally I want to have only up to one pending Thread of execution while this recalculation is done. Or maybe I don't get the idea here?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  You want this method to only lock other accesses of this method, and not block anything else including getters, right?

Comment: Yes, the `@AccessTimeout` becomes meaningless in this case.  If you want a timed wait, then you would use your own ReentrantReadWriteLock (or whatever) rather than the synchronized keyword.

Comment: (+1) This looks promising now, tyvm!  -  Going to test and accept the answer later on, currently busy with christmas preparation :-)

Comment: @aguibert There is a race between tryLock and lock that can cause the lock to block indefinitely.  Instead, you want `tryLock(long, TimeUnit)` to do a timed wait, which I suspect is how nearly all EJB containers implement `@AccessTimeout`.

Comment: @BrettKail thanks for pointing that out.  One could argue that this scenario is rare enough that it still outweighs having an `@AccessTimeout` (or equivalent), so I updated the first option with a disclaimer, and added a third option based on `tryLock(long, TimeUnit)`.  As always, appreciate the code review =)

Answer (score 2):

I would rather discourage you from mixing container-managed concurrency with manual synchronization. I believe it is better to use bean-managed concurrency and JavaSE synchronization techniques to have better control of what is going on. Just use @ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN) annotation and lock access to your methods the way you want.

You may also try to keep using container-managed concurrency and split your logic for two separate singletons, first for data reading, second for long running stuff. The second one can provide the first one with results once their are collected, using quick, locked method just for old data replacement with a fresh, calculated portion of data.